# g++ error:word64 does not name a type

Tags: c++, c, g++, 64-bit

I was trying to compile a software package, While compiling I am getting this error

```
sha.cpp:29: error: ‘word64’ does not name a type
```

I went through the source code.The relevant portion is

```
#if HAVE64
    word64 bytes;
#else
    word32 bytesHi, bytesLo;
#endif
```

from sha.cpp, Line No 29-33

And I found that word64 was declared in the following way in another file

```
#include <limits.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#if UCHAR_MAX == 0xff
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef signed char int8;
#else
#error This machine has no 8-bit type
#endif

#if UINT_MAX == 0xffff
typedef uint word16;
typedef int int16;
#elif USHRT_MAX == 0xffff
typedef unsigned short word16;
typedef short int16;
#else
#error This machine has no 16-bit type
#endif

#if UINT_MAX == 0xfffffffful
typedef uint word32;
typedef int int32;
#elif ULONG_MAX == 0xfffffffful
typedef ulong word32;
typedef long int32;
#else
#error This machine has no 32-bit type
#endif

#if ULONG_MAX > 0xfffffffful
#if ULONG_MAX == 0xfffffffffffffffful
typedef ulong bnword64;
#define BNWORD64 bnword64
#define HAVE64 1
#endif
#endif



#ifndef HAVE64
#if defined(ULONG_LONG_MAX) || defined (ULLONG_MAX) || defined(ULONGLONG_MAX)
typedef unsigned long long word64;
typedef long long int64;
#define HAVE64 1
#endif
#endif
```

And my system is

```
Linux EmbeddedLinux 2.6.32-431.1.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Nov 24 09:37:37 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The compiler I am using to compile

```
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
```

I browsed internet to get this thing fixed, but did not find any clue.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: There seems to be missing a `typedef` for `word64` and `word32`. Have you searched the code base for that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if the PO would comment on how things went, if he/she tried anything and did work or not?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a header file somewhere, where word64 and word32 are defined. Try to find that library with a text search. If you don't find the library, then it is difficult to figure out what the author of the library was trying to define as word63/32.

You could try with the following guess (and it is a guess, so it might not work): add the following lines to sha.cpp, before the fragment you quoted:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint64_t word64;
typedef uint32_t word32;
```

Alternatively, if that doesn't work, try this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef int64_t word64;
typedef int32_t word32;
```

Good luck!

Comment: You mistyped type names; it should be `typedef uint64_t word64; typedef int64_t int64;`

Comment: You're right, keltar. The dangers of working off the top of my head... It's now edited. Thank you!